# How should a web app use my public API

Tags: api, http, oauth

I'm developing a public HTTP backend API for a service. On top of that, there is a web app that has users log in, and should use the backend API to fulfill user requests. The API supports OAuth2, and the web app is a single page app, with loads of javascript.

My concern is how the browser and the web app should talk with the API. I found two possible ways.

#### Browser directly uses the API

When the user enters his credentials to log in, the web app passes them to the API and is given an OAuth access_token, which is directly passed to the browser and stored in some cookie. Then every request to the API is made directly from the browser through JSONP. When the user logs out, the web app destroys the session.

#### Browser talks to web app, which talks to the API

When the user enters his credentials to log in, the web app passes them to the API and is given an OAuth access_token. A session is created with the User and the access_token is stored in the session. When the browser needs to talk to the API, it goes through the web app. The web app uses the access token in the session, calls the API, and delivers the response to the browser.

Both ways have pros and cons with performance and security trade offs. What do you think?

PS: from what I've seen, twitter uses it's public API directly from the browser, but passes session cookies for authentication. That means their API also supports cookie sessions?

Comment: WHat did you end up with? I'm in the same situation.

Comment: @sandelius directly talking with the API. But I'm concerned with SEO.

Answer (score 0):

Dan,

The options you mentioned are the commonly used options.
You have a presentation layer(UI) and a business layer(API)
Which one to choose is a question of how many layers you want in your application based on the complexity and extendability you may need in future. 
You may want to introduce a middle layer if there is a big gap between your API layer and your UI.
If the gap is high you will want a layer for the extra processing , abstracting the complexities and to keep your UI layer clutter free.

But if all you need, is a simple processing in your UI layer on top of API layer go for Option 1